# xcode4 git push error 403 while accessing git repo

Tags: git, xcode4, git-push, git-commit

I recently upgraded to OS Lion and Xcode4 and cloned a git repo of mine to start working on.  The clone worked fine and I can commit changes I've made successfully to my repo but when I try to push the changes I get the following error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing 
https://sadmicrowave@github.com/sadmicrowave/iOS-Time-Blogger.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

What is wrong? I've added my Mac SSH key to my github profile, but I don't know why I'm having this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the authentication was failing while using the https URI.  I deleted the original cloned repo and recloned it using the git/ssh address which asked me to authenticate and now works for pushes, pulls, merges, and commits.